# Java Syntax: What does this phrase mean?

Tags: java

What does this phrase mean in Java?
I assume it means that a previously defined variable named "treeCopy" is calling its left source method, which in turn is assigned to the variable "leftCopy".

Am I correct? Remotely close? Totally wrong?

```
    leftCopy = treeCopy(source.left);

    public static <E> BTNode<E> treeCopy(BTNode<E> source)
{
    BTNode<E> leftCopy, rightCopy;

    if (source == null)

        return null;
    else
    {
        leftCopy = treeCopy(source.left);

        rightCopy = treeCopy(source.right);

        return new BTNode<E>(source.data, leftCopy, rightCopy);
    }
}
```

Comment: it means that it is a comment which will be ignored by the compiler

Comment: treecopy is a method. Hold on, why don't you show some more code to give the context?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:  I removed my comment markers.

Comment: @ivanovic: If I am totally wrong, can you help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No one here can tell you what this code means beyond :

- It's an assignment of some variable called `leftCopy` from the result of some method `treeCopy`
- The method `treeCopy` takes a parameter, in this case whatever is in `source.left`
- It won't execute because it's commented out

Consider reading how to ask a [question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: Don´t tell no one, of you cannot.

Comment: @Amir Afghani: Thank you so much friend. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @AlexWien: What did you say? I don't understand you. Type more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo: it should be "Dont say 'No one' if you cannot tell"; It is visible at first sight that this is a tree copy of the left subtree

Comment: My point was that you cannot know without seeing the actual implementation.

Comment: @AmirAfghani:  Thanks, friend! I found the answer I was looking for.  Appreciate it much. =-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tree with a node or a root "Source" from source two branches emanate. A left and a right branch. TreeCopy is a function that takes a node as an input and returns a subtree in this case the left sub tree of source.

Comment: thank you very much. I was looking for an explanation of this kind.  What does it mean when you use the period in Java to connect two Java keywords. For example, "source.right"    What is the period doing between these two keywords.  Thanks.

Comment: Source is an object that has at least two members left and right. Source { left, right}. To access a certain member of Source you use the dot operator.

Comment: @-timsa7: Thanks. That's what I had to clarify, but I found the answer on my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code copies the left subtree of an binary tree.